# Can an esoteric magus tattoo his chosen spell at 6th level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus, archetype

The [Esoteric Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/esoteric-magus-archetype/) has a feature that reads

> **Tattooed Spell (Sp)**
>
> At 5th level and every 6 levels thereafter, an esoteric can
>   permanently tattoo one spell from his magus spellbook onto his body;
>   the first tattooed spell must be of 2nd level or lower, the second
>   must be of 4th level or lower, and the last can be of any level. The
>   spell that is tattooed must not have an expensive material component
>   or a focus. (...)

The thing is, I would like to get [Spell Blending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/spell-blending-ex/) as my 6th level arcana and tattoo the wizard spell I get from it. Is it possible to put off tattooing the spell until 6th level?

I understand that you can't put off gaining class features, but if the class feature gives you the ability to do something, you might be able to put off doing that thing.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Please stop using the comments to write “this isn't an answer…” and then writing an answer. Answers are only for helping the post be improved; an attempt to help solve the problem, even in a way not asked for, is an answer, not a comment. We cannot have answer material in comments because comments do not support features like proper voting and the wiki-style editing that allow us to vet and improve the content — the entire point of RPG.se.

Answer (score 2):

### No, they cannot. But the GM should allow it.

The [Tattooed Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/esoteric-magus-archetype/) ability is gained at 5th level, then again at 11th and 16th, and there is no mention that you can wait to pick your tattooed spells later.

However, the ability does not force you to make this tattoo, its an option, if you decide not to tattoo a spell on your body, then you won't have it.

> an esoteric **can** permanently tattoo one spell from his magus spellbook onto his body;

Normally, a class feature cannot be replaced later without some special rule allowing you to, like a [sorcerer's known spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/) or a [fighter's bonus feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/#TOC-Bonus-Feats).

### Retraining

[Retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/) (optional system from *ultimate campaign*) could be an option if your GM allows it. With this system, replacing any class feature by another is restricted, you cannot retrain everything on your class, but for monks, you are allowed to retrain your *bonus feats*. Since this ability replaces your bonus feats, at GM discretion, you should be allowed to retrain it:

> **If an archetype or variant class feature replaces the listed class feature, at the GM’s discretion you may retrain that alternative class feature for an equivalent variant class feature**. For example, inquisitions, which inquisitors can select in place of a domain, and the inquisitor entry below allows you to retrain your chosen domain, so you are allowed to instead retrain an inquisition, swapping it for a domain or another inquisition.